# Character cannot be represented in character set in CLISP (2.49)

Tags: windows, encoding, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Im trying to use CLISP on Windows. So, when I start it in Command line I see next

```
*** - SYSTEM::DRIVER: Character #\u0414 cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:cp437
Break 1 [3]>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

## [This is an FAQ](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-enc-err):

### What do these error messages mean: “invalid byte #x94 in CHARSET:ASCII conversion” and “character #\u00B3 cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:ASCII”?

This means that you are trying to read (“invalid byte”) or write (“character cannot be represented”) a non-ASCII character from (or to) a character stream which has ASCII `:EXTERNAL-FORMAT`. The default is described in `-Edomain encoding`.

This may also be caused by filesystem access. If you have files with names incompatible with your `CUSTOM:*PATHNAME-ENCODING*`, filesystem access (e.g., `DIRECTORY`) will `SIGNAL` this `ERROR`. You will need to set `CUSTOM:*PATHNAME-ENCODING*` or pass `-Edomain encoding` to CLISP. Using a “1:1” encoding, such as `CHARSET:ISO-8859-1`, should help you avoid this error.

Note that this error may be signaled by the “Print” part of the read-eval-print loop and not by the function you call. E.g., if file "foo" contains non-ASCII characters, you will see such an error when you type

```
(WITH-OPEN-FILE (s "foo"
                 :direction :input
                 :EXTERNAL-FORMAT CHARSET:ISO-8859-1)
  (READ-LINE s))
```

If instead you type

```
(WITH-OPEN-FILE (s "foo"
                 :direction :input
                 :EXTERNAL-FORMAT CHARSET:ISO-8859-1)
  (SETQ l (READ-LINE s))
  NIL)
```

CLISP will just print NIL and signal the error when you type l.

Answer (score 1):

`cp437` seems to indicate a code page.  Code page 437 is "US-ASCII" if I remember correctly, that is only 7 bits.  It seems that you need to configure your "Command line" to display unicode.